# MS Graph API - Combining And/Or into Filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, calendarview

I'm trying to use the OData `$filter` query parameter with the `calendarView` endpoint in MS Graph. It seems to work fine until I combine `AND` with `OR`. Does anyone know the proper syntax?

```
Private Sub buildQuery()
    m_webQuery = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/calendar/calendarView"
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "?$select=subject,organizer, start,end"
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&startDateTime=" & Format$(m_projectStart, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&endDateTime=" & Format$(m_projectStart + 365, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$filter= (contains(subject,'PTO') or contains(subject,'OOO')) and organizer/emailAddress/name eq 'John Doe'"
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$orderby=organizer/emailAddress/name"
    m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$top=500"
End Sub
```

**The filter failing to produce correct results**

```
m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$filter= contains(subject,'PTO') or contains(subject,'OOO') and organizer/emailAddress/name eq 'Joe Smith'"
```

The result should be any event containing PTO or OOO in the subject where the organizer is John Doe

I've tried combining using parans but no avail.

Answer (score 1):

From the testing it's not possible to combine filtering by `organizer/emailAddress/name` together with filtering by any other property.

So either

```
m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$filter= contains(subject,'PTO') or contains(subject,'OOO')"
```

or

```
m_webQuery = m_webQuery & "&$filter=organizer/emailAddress/name eq 'John Doe'"
```

will work.

Only solution is to use one of the filter above for server side filtering and then apply the other filter on the client.